# How to use cert-manager with nginx ingress controller and avoid "host collusion" issue?

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, lets-encrypt

I recently updated the nginx-controller in my kubernetes cluster. The current behavior when multiple ingress resources are defined is "choose winner". Meaning that if there are 2 ingress resources to the same host, nginx will only define one of them, instead of merging the paths.

The way to get around this seems to be documented [here](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/tree/v2.3.0/examples/mergeable-ingress-types), which describes the solution by adding annotations of `nginx.org/mergeable-ingress-type`.

However, to the best of my knowledge, cert-manager does not create the ingresses with these annotation. Resulting with a 404 for the challenge url (or worse: a 404 to the site I'm trying to create a certificate for)

Here is the ingress serving the site:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: farmers
  annotations:
    nginx.org/mergeable-ingress-type: "master"
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  - host: farmers.klino.me
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: frontend
            port:
              number: 80
```

And the ingress of the challenge:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range: 0.0.0.0/0,::/0
  generateName: cm-acme-http-solver-
  generation: 3
  labels:
    acme.cert-manager.io/http-domain: "..."
    acme.cert-manager.io/http-token: "..."
    acme.cert-manager.io/http01-solver: "true"
  name: cm-acme-http-solver-7677r
  namespace: staging
spec:
  rules:
  - host: farmers.klino.me
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: cm-acme-http-solver-hkx6g
            port:
              number: 8089
        path: /.well-known/acme-challenge/<...reducted...>
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
```

In summary, I have 2 ingress resources to the host `farmers.klino.me`, on serving the site at `/`, the other - created automatically by certmanager - serving the challenge at `/.well-known/acme-challenge/<...reducted...>`.

How should I configure the nginx-ingress and cert-manager to merge the ingresses and work together without human intervention?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** There appears to be two different NGINX Ingress controller deployments. One called [nginx-ingress](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/nginx/nginx-ingress) and the other called [ingress-nginx](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx)

The one you want is [ingress-nginx](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx). This version automatically merges the ingress rules created by cert-manager and instantly all my certificates renewed. The controller documentation can be found [here](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/) and the cert-manager documentation found [here](https://cert-manager.io/docs/tutorials/acme/nginx-ingress/) is applicable.

Hope this helps!

**Original Post:**
I'm also experiencing the same issue. I've not yet tried it but it looks like you can configure an ingressTemplate for your given issuer. For example:

```yaml
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: Issuer
metadata:
  name: ...
spec:
  acme:
    server: ...
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: ...
    solvers:
    - http01:
        ingress:
          ingressTemplate:
            metadata:
              labels:
                foo: "bar"
              annotations:
                "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range": "0.0.0.0/0,::/0"
                "nginx.org/mergeable-ingress-type": "minion"
                "traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/frontend-entry-points": "http"
```

See https://cert-manager.io/v1.6-docs/configuration/acme/http01/#ingresstemplate for more details.

This doesn't seem like the most efficient way to handle this issue though so if anyone has a better solution I'm all ears.

Comment: Replacing my ingress controller from nginx-ingress to ingress-nginx did the trick. Didn't try to suggested solution from your original answer though